# Requirement for explicit transaction statements when using SET XACT_ABORT ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

If I use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, do I have to wrap all my statements under explicit transaction statements: `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`?

Or does `SET XACT_ABORT ON` terminate procedure execution regardless of these in the case of execution error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XACT_ABORT is typically for when someone has coded a transaction in a stored procedure, when maybe they should have left this responsibility to the calling module.

When something goes wrong, a transaction can remain open with the caller being oblivious to it. Setting XACT_ABORT to ON means that the transaction is not left open in the event of a failure.

When using transaction, you should really always look to handle every possible error within the SQL and deal with the transaction accordingly. Better still, strip the transactions from the SQL altogether, and rely on the calling module.